# xdg-mime not behaving

Tags: mime-types, defaults

I am trying to set the default application for magnet links using:

```
~ $ xdg-mime default deluge.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet
```

Checking this with `grep -i deluge ~/.local/share/applications/*`
 yeilds:

```
 /home/manko/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list:x-scheme-handler/magnet=deluge.desktop
 /home/manko/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list:application/x-bittorrent=deluge.desktop
```

i.e. it should have worked right?!? c.f:

```
~ $ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet
deluge.desktop
```

However when I run `xdg-open magnet:?xt=urn:btih:6fa3fa92...` chromium fires up!

I'm stumped.

Comment: What does `xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet` return ?

Comment: @don_crissti `deluge.desktop`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [this patch](http://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2012/01/24/open-magnet-urls-with-xdg-open/) for `xdg-open`, which just hardcodes deluge.

Hack central but does the job, and at least taught me that `xdg-open` is a script which I can play with.

Answer (score 0):

For me, further to running the `xdg-mime default <your file type>` command, it was running

```
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/
```

which finally updated the default application.

After this, running `xdg-mime query default <your file type>` now showed the new default application.